# react conflit package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » D:\Projets\Roster's\Client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » D:\Projets\Roster's\client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

Answer (score 0):

try

solution 1 : save your package file (ctrl + s).

solution 2: `npm uninstall eslint-config-react-app` or `yarn remove eslint-config-react-app`

then

`npm i eslint-config-react-app@6` or `yarn add eslint-config-react-app@6`

Answer (score 0):

The path you cd'ed into from the terminal has different capitalization than the real path, see that one has "Client" and the other "client".

D:\Projets\Roster's\Client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js
D:\Projets\Roster's\client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js

You should check that when you cd into the directory, you use the same exact capitalization as the real path.

I had the same problem, and this is what solved it for me.